# Using regex to reformat text

Tags: ruby, regex

Is there a way to use regex to reformat a string?

I've a string like this `AEY4293` and I want to add a dash between letters and numbers, like this `AEY-4293`.

I was trying to find something like `s/pattern/replacement/`, but I couldn't find it.

I can select the blocks using `/(\w+)(\d+)/` so if I could give to a pattern to reformat the text like `\1-\2` it would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: What programming language are you using?  The correct answer to your question depends on the language's regular expression implementation. Edit: I see you tagged this as "ruby" - didn't notice that earlier. Sorry.

Comment: So, are you going to pick an answer?  ;)

Comment: Thanks you all. After you mentioned the method I saw I was displicent while reading the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001185). I really didn't saw this method. I feel so noob :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
irb(main):001:0> "AEY4293".sub(/(\D+)(\d+)/, '\1-\2')
=> "AEY-4293"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'AEY4293'.sub(/(?<=\w)(?=\d)/, '-')
```

You can also do

```
'AEY4293'.sub(/(?=\d)/, '-')
```

which comes close to mu is too short's answer.

Comment: @mu is too short It gave me `AEY-4293`.

Comment: @mu is too short. It was `/(?<\w)(?=\d)/`, which was an invalid regex, then I immediately corrected it. I didn't think you tried my wrong regex. Yeah, right before that, it was `/\w(?=\d)/` for a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Regex would be:

```
/([A-Z]+)(\d+)/
```

Replacement pattern would be:

```
\1-\2
```

There is a problem with expression `/(\w+)(\d+)/`, because `\w` matches both alpha and numbers.
So, with input `AEY4293`,  `\w+` will match `AEY429` and `\d+` will match trailing `3`.

Answer (score 1):

If the non-numeric prefix is always three characters then you can do it without a regular expression:

```
s = 'AEY4293'
s[3,0] = '-'
# s is now 'AEY-4293'
```

Or, if you want a little more flexibility on the prefix size, you can use [`index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001142) combined with the above:

```
s[s.index(/\d/), 0] = '-'
```

I like the bracket-assignment notation for this as it matches up nicely with your intent.

Comment: +1 for TMTOWTDI, but -1 because OP asked for regex HOWTO ... ;)

Comment: @dossy: Fair enough, just trying to avoid the "all I have is a hammer" syndrome :)

Comment: Indeed - it's good to remember that Ruby's string-as-an-array paradigm is really powerful.

Comment: @dossy: And a lot of people (such as me) get locked into trying to make a solution work when a whole new approach would be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `str.sub(pattern, replacement)` method for that. Replacement is a sting with `\1` and so on references.